# insufficient memory to create an excel workbook

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

My original code:

```
    Excel.Application xlErrorApp;
    Excel.Workbook xlErrorWorkBook;
    Excel.Worksheet xlErrorWorkSheet;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    xlErrorApp = new Excel.Application();
    xlErrorWorkBook = xlErrorApp.Workbooks.Add(); // -> error
    xlErrorWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlErrorWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```

A get error in line 6.

Error Message:

> Application Microsoft Excel can not open or save documents due to
>   insufficient memory or disk space.

Comment: What is the error? Please be more specific.

Comment: I just tested your code and it runs fine (it needs tidied up though), what version of C# are you using, and could it be that you actually are low on RAM/disk space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry I could not find the link earlier. I used EPPlus supports. http://epplus.codeplex.com

Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 2):

Which library are you using ?

I already said it but actually Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

I recommend you to look for a free library like Open Office XML or a not free library like Aspose.

Comment: It's impossible because users use only excel files on local machines.

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Workbooks.Add()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.add.aspx) method from *MSDN*;

```
Parameters
Template
Type: System.Object
```

> Optional Object. Determines how the new workbook is created. If this
>   argument is a string specifying the name of an existing Microsoft
>   Excel file, the new workbook is created with the specified file as a
>   template. If this argument is a constant, the new workbook contains a
>   single sheet of the specified type. Can be one of the following
>   XlWBATemplate constants: xlWBATChart, xlWBATExcel4IntlMacroSheet,
>   xlWBATExcel4MacroSheet, or xlWBATWorksheet. If this argument is
>   omitted, Microsoft Excel creates a new workbook with a number of blank
>   sheets (the number of sheets is set by the SheetsInNewWorkbook
>   property).

If you try to create new workbook, try like this;

```
Workbook newWorkbook = this.Application.Workbooks.Add(missing);
```

Comment: Yes. At first i did like you wrote. It's not important in that case.